# Trying to figure out OpenGLES and its "space"

Tags: android, opengl-es

Currently I'm working on an Application involving OpenGL ES 2.0. I'm using the Java Wrapper for it, since the OpenGL part will probably not have the biggest complexity ever. Nontheless, I'm currently stuck.

First, I'm trying to draw something like this: 
[image: But no rounded corners etc..]

So I just want to draw some sort of indicator, how big my "space" is - if there even are limitations? How would I draw such a cage around the center of the camera? (Of course I just want a simple one, basically a square, indicating boundaries, not something with rounded borders etc)

Answer (score 0):

To draw something like this without rounded corners I suggest you to simply draw a textured cube (there are too many of those around the web). For it to look as nice as the one on the image you will also need to add some lights into the scene as they are the ones that give a true 3d effect (a sphere without shades/lights will always appear as a 2d circle).

As for the limitations: There are no specific limitations in size except the overflow. I think in most cases you have a 32-bit floating values in your vectors so its maximum value would be how big is your space. Other limitations are more of a visual, you usually use frustum for this type of scene which has parameters `zNear` and `zFar` clipping plains. These two will define you can not see pixels nearer then `zNear` or further then `zFar`. Although you can set your own value for `zFar` and can be very large you should know there is a penalty in depth buffer precision doing so (result can be incorrect drawing when 2 objects are too close together).

So in general you are the one that has to take care of the scene scale or size and consider your field of view.